# Symbol compute of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: symbolic, symbols

If i have the Lagrange density function $$L(x,\dot{x}) =  \frac{1}{2}x^2+ \frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2,$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation is very simple by

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}  - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}  = 0$$

In this example, E-L equation is $\ddot{x}-x=0.$

Can i do this in MMA symbol computation? I know i can use `’` and `D` to take derivative,  so i define `l=0.5x^2+0.5x'^2` as Lagrange density function, and then `Diff[D[l,x']]-D[l,x]`, the result seems not right, maybe i need define `l` as a function of `t`?

I have no experience in symbolic calculations. Can you share some interesting examples? in MMA SE, seems not much symbol computation topic.

And any comments very much appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
ClearAll[x, t]
L = 1/2*x[t]^2 + 1/2*x'[t]^2;
EulerEquations[L, x[t], t]
```

$$
x(t)-x''(t)=0
$$

> can i realize it by ’ and ‘D’?

Sure. You could always apply the definition yourself. The above command just makes it easier.

```
 D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]] == 0
```

$$
x''(t)-x(t)=0
$$

Comment: Big shot, amazing! Thank you, by the way, can i realize it by `’` and ‘D’? It is more general, suppose E-L have some different definition, and didn’t have `EulerEquations`.